# Appmaker: How to validate my data on the server-side before creating a record?

Tags: validation, server, client, google-app-maker

I have a form, which has to check that some of its fields' values are unique.

I have a text box which would show the error based on the response from the server. I can only check the uniqueness with a server side query, but I don't know how to get the result back to the client side, since server-side scripts can't call client side scripts, only the other way around.

Maybe I should find another way to handle the validation, any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where exactly do you have your validation for uniqueness? Custom server function, model onBeforeCreate or onAfterCreate events, or as a model field setting for ‘Unique’?

Comment: I have the field setting 'Unique' for several fields I need to be unique, but after submitting a record, only the console informs me that the record creation failed if one of those fields is not unique. I wanted to run a validator script in the onBeforeCreate event, to send back information to the client, which would show the cause of error in a text box.

Comment: So you will want to do widget.datasource.createItem({success: function() {//do something here}, failure: function(error) {label.text = error.message;}}). However this will only return a generic ‘Server Error’ from the server for everyone that is not an admin.

Comment: Thank you that already helps a lot! So there is no way for me to run a query on those fields' uniqueness, and process the results on the client side?

Comment: You can run that query in the onBeforeCreate event and then use ‘throw new app.ManagedError(‘your custom message here’) in conjunction with the above submit button click event and that would return a custom message. Just keep in mind it can slow down performance depending on how many individual queries you run.

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks again, I really appreciate it!